# How to make image move and bounce off in the enclosed rectangle shape using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

May i know of any examples or codes, whereby i can animate the small image to move about and let it bounce off the wall of a given rectangle using Jquery??

Many thanks for taking time to read this questions..

Answer (score 0):

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is a powerful visualization engine that has some physics-based examples you can follow.